# Does Properties.Resources returns a new object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43652487/9404007) Hans Passant mentions that:

> Project > Properties > Resources is notable in this story. It provides very convenient syntax to use a bitmap resource in your program. But it is dangerous, just about nobody realizes that every time they use Properties.Resources.Somename in their code, they get a brand-new Bitmap object that must be disposed.

But inspecting the internal implementation of `ResourceManager.GetObject`, I find something like this:

```cs
// namespace System.Resources.ResourceSet
private object GetObjectInternal(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    }

    Hashtable table = Table;
    if (table == null)
    {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("ObjectDisposed_ResourceSet"));
    }

    return table[name];
}
```

I suspect that the `Hashtable` here caches the resourses which is just opposite to what Hans says.

My question is:

1. Does `Properties.Resources.Somename` return a *brand new* object each time?
2. Even so, GC will dispose `Disposable` objects no longer used. As long as I don't get objects by `Properties.Resourses` fast enough that eats up memory, I suppose that won't be a problem?

Comment: Sorry, the GC **never** disposes `IDisposable` objects.  There's nothing magic about IDisposable - you write the Dispose method on your classes, and you call Dispose methods on objects that you manage.  If a class has a `Finalizer` (aka a _Destructor_) and that is not suppressed, then the GC mechanism will queue it for a later call

Comment: There's no need to ask us whether it returns a new object each time. Just get the property value twice and compare to see whether they are the same object. You  never need to ask us something that you can test for yourself.

Comment: As for disposing, that's something you do in your code. The GC will finalize objects that have not been disposed but it will take longer to perform the full cleanup if you don't dispose explicitly. Note that disposing does reclaim memory but it does mean that the GC can reclaim the memory occupied by the object sooner. Just dispose everything that you can when you are done with it and you know don't have to wonder whether you're doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Fair enough, I get the resource twice and they really are two different objects. I'd better create a new static class to cache the object myself.

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks for the remind, I was wrong about GC and `IDisposable`.

Comment: For the record, that should have been "Note that disposing does NOT reclaim memory...".

Answer (score 2):

Votedown on the question is reasonable, I just want to clarify that:

1. Hans is right, it does returns a brand new object.
2. Ignore what I posted in the question, GC and `IDisposable` does not have necessary relationship.